# What are other alternatives in declaring another class' type as attribute for another class in php

Tags: php

I've been reading on some references and questions here in SO about PHP object types. Coming from a Java programming background, I'm still trying to get myself used with how PHP handle types and objects and how I can properly model my classes considering that PHP is not strongly typed.

So, let's say I have a class called `User` and `Role` Now, since every `User` should have a `Role`, I need to declare a `$role` variable within `User` class. As in,

```
class Role{
    private $roleId;
    function getRoleId(){...}
    function setRoleId(){...}
}

class User{
    private $role;    
}
```

I can easily declare a `$role` variable without any type but when I try to access the `get()` and `set()` methods of `Role` I won't be able to automatically show the `get()` and `set()` when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

For example if I have a dao implementation class that might return a `User` instance which has its attributes set with values, I won't be able to declare the type of `$role` to `Role`

```
$user = $userDaoImpl->getUser(); //returns new User();
$role = $user->getRole(); //return $role without a type
```

then if I try to do something like,

```
$role->getRoleId(); // i have to manually type get..Role..Id()..
```

Unless I follow the `TypeHinting` option suggested by other members here in SO.

All because I can't declare `$role` like

```
class User{
    private Role $role';
}
```

So my question to those who primarily program in PHP is, how do you model your classes in cases like with `Role` being an attribute of `User` if you cannot specify the type?

I'd appreciate any suggestion. I'm fairly new with PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: In user public getRole(): ?Role { return $this->role; } public setRole(Role $role): self { $this->role = $role; return $this; } and annotation for role @var Role and you can add declare(strict_types=1); at the top of your php script.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDE's will honour [Docblock](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php) comments for the type hint..

```
class User{
    /**
     * @var Role
     */
    private  $role;
}
```

Note that this has no pragmatical impact on your code and will allow any  value to be put into the $role field.  This is more an annotation than anything enforced by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is instantiation;

```
// Create the role class
class Role{
    private $roleId;      
    public function getRoleId(){return $this->roleId;}
    public function setRoleId($roleid){$this->roleId = $roleid;}
}
// Create the user class
class User{
    private $role;    
    // Give it a constructor so that the role object can be instantiated
    public function __construct($roleid)
    {
        $this->role = new Role();
        // Set and get the role id
        $this->role->setRoleId($roleid);
        print $this->role->getRoleId();
    }
}
```

Another way to do this, inheritance;

```
// Create the roll class
class Role
{
    // Protect the "roleid" so it can be used in child classes
    // but not outside of
    protected $roleId;
    function getRoleId(){return $this->roleId;}
    function setRoleId(){$this->roleId = $roleid;}
}

// Create the user class and extend role
class User extends Role
{
    // Create a constructor
    public function __construct($roleid)
    {
        // Set and print the role id
        $this->setRoleId($roleid);
        print $this->getRoleId();
    }
}
```

Either way is acceptable, but inheritance is better as it gives the child all attributes of the parent directly (apart from private which are available to parent only)

You don't need to specify a "Role" object inside the "User" class, simply extend it's functionality by inheriting it to a child class, this also means if you need roles on "Contacts" as well for example, you can extend it there too and have it's functions available

Also - as Nigel's answer says, Docblock is a good one to use also